# default ios background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, background-image

I want to use such background for my app. This image is from ios 6. Is it the way to programatically attach it to the view. Don't want to include this image in project and use UIImage view since it has already stored in ios

[image]

Comment: I don't think Apple let's you do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by selecting **Background** of your View in *Attributes inspector*, select **other** and then third tab -> iPhone/iPad SDK -> ScrollViewTexturedBackground (like on the screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

UIColor class has the following class method

```
+ (UIColor *)scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor
```

try to set background color.

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: Deprecated Not a good solution.